# How To get Email of the Current User in a Data Form WebPart

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have to pass in the email address of the current user to a web service data source (run time) of a DataForm Web Part.

My Question is:

a) How can I get Email address of a user based on login in DVWP?
I know we can get the CurrentUser using the CurrentUserName but how do we get the Email for the Current User.

b) After getting the Email how to we pass to the Web Service runtime?

Note: In XSL

Comment: Have you subclassed the DVWP?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/05/24/sharepoint-mailto-hyperlink-in-a-dvwp/

Comment: +1 for linking to my article :-)

Answer (score 0):

Embedding all of that in xsl is pretty painful.  Your best bet is to use something like SPServices (jQuery) which has a GetCurrentUser function and put it on the page with the DVWP.  The script can get the current user, call a web service, and even update the contents of the DVWP if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the SPSerives route on the master page that for some reason did not work for me. I took the server side approach wrote a custom control to get it working. Deployed the custom control project replaced <cc2:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="username" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="abc" Name="username"></cc2:DataFormParameter> with the new tag for the custom control <abc:UserProfileParameter PropertyName="WorkEmail" DefaultValue="abc" Name="UserEmailAddress"></abc:UserProfileParameter> within the SelectParameter in Data source String in the .webpart file. This way I got the user profile information pass to the web service.